# Return data object from fs.createReadStream

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm trying to read a TSV file, and doing it in two parts. The header info is written in 2 column and the main data is written in 7 column. So two pass to build up a final excel doc with this info. In any case, I've organized my read functions into another file which I call in my main express route file, all of this from an uploaded file. I keep getting an 'UNDEFINED' on the returned data in the main route file, though a console log of the data before the return is the correct format, an array of Object(s). I'm confused as to how I'd return this data back to the calling file (function). I'd like to separate my logic if possible.

-------- ROUTE FILE

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const authorize = require('../../helpers/authorize');
const multer = require('multer');
const {
    parseHeaderInfoFromEdl,
    parsedMusicTracksFromEdl,
} = require('../../helpers/createMusicEdl');

// Multer configuration
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/');
    },

    // By default, multer removes file extensions so let's add them back
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
});

// Multer upload strategy
let upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/edl', upload.single('edl'), (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Check for file, return if no file found
        if (!req.file) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'No file uploaded',
            });
        }

        let filename = req.file.originalname;

        // Parse out the header information
        let header = parseHeaderInfoFromEdl(filename);
        console.log(header);   <------- returns UNDEFINED

        res.status(200).json(header);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Error creating EDL',
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

---- FUNCTION FILE

```
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = { parsedMusicTracksFromEdl, parseHeaderInfoFromEdl };

let uploadsDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../uploads');

function parseHeaderInfoFromEdl(filename) {
    let edlDataFromReadStream = [];
    let edlHeaderInfo = [];

    // Read the uploaded document and parse out the first 5 rows
    fs.createReadStream(uploadsDirectory + '/' + filename)
        .pipe(
            // Parse data using 'fast-csv', limit to 5 rows for header information only
            csv.parse({
                delimiter: '\t',
                maxRows: 5,
                trim: true,
            })
        )
        .on('error', (error) => console.error(error))
        .on('data', (row) => {
            // Build up row by row, the header information from the read doc
            edlDataFromReadStream.push(row);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            // Map out the headers to a cleaner structure
            edlDataFromReadStream.map((element) => {
                edlHeaderInfo = {
                    'Name': element[1],
                    'Sample Rate': element[1],
                    'Bit Depth': element[1],
                    'Session Start Timecode': element[1],
                    'Timecode Format': element[1],
                };
            });
            console.log(edlHeaderInfo);  <----- returns correct format
            return edlHeaderInfo;
        });
}

function parsedMusicTracksFromEdl(path, filename) {
    let parsedFile = [];
    let correctedFile = [];

    fs.createReadStream(path, filename)
        .pipe(
            csv.parse({
                headers: true,
                delimiter: '\t',
                skipLines: 15,
                trim: true,
            })
        )
        .on('error', (error) => console.error(error))
        .on('data', (row) => {
            parsedFile.push(row);
        })
        .on('end', (rowCount) => {
            parsedFile
                .filter((r) => {
                    return r['CHANNEL'] == '1';
                })
                .map((row) => {
                    correctedFile.push({
                        Filename: row['CLIP NAME'],
                        'Start TC': row['START TIME'],
                        'End TC': row['END TIME'],
                        Duration: row['DURATION'],
                    });
                    return;
                });
            return correctedFile;
        });
}
```

Comment: parseHeaderInfoFromEdl(filename);  is aSync and you are not waiting for a promise to resolve at the onEnd event on the stream in the called function doing the async action

Comment: This worked. Wasn’t seeing type of function in docs. Thanks. Wrapped it in promise and called then on calling function. All good. Thanks!